# how to add link in a line in phpword from dynamic data?

Tags: php

I am making a word document from dynamic data  but whole line comes like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNyqw.png) and i want my line like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnOGs.png) is there any method in php word to do like this.

```php
$section->addLink(
    $data[$j]['ArticleURL'],
    cleanstring($data[$j]['publicationPrint']).formatDateForEmail(
        $data[$k]['previewDate']),
    $linkFontStyleName,
    $fontStyleIndexPara);
```

Comment: what is your `$section`?

Comment: removed rude initial sentence and reformatted code for better readability

Comment: i wrote it in my code please check it bro @BhargavChudasama

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you gave us, I think it would be like that:

```
$section->addLink(
    'The Indian Wire',
    [
        'url'=> 'link href...'
        'font'=> 'font name...'
        'color'=> 'text color...'

    ]
);
$section->addText(' | July-4-2019 | By - Bureau');
```

See the doc: [phpdocx.com/api-documentation/](https://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/word-content/insert-link-Word-document-with-PHP)

Comment: thanks for your answer i really appreciate but i'm using phpword library and youare suggesting me php docx. library method.